# PHP function to output pictures randomly according to attribute

Tags: php, cakephp, php-5.6

I am wondering if it's possible to output randomly some pictures if a certain attribute is added on a product. I am just learning php and I would like to test some things...
Let's say I add 10 diffrent pictures of fish plates and I would like to output always 2 of them on a product page where the product has the attribute "fish" on food recommendation.
How can I do this the most easiest way on PHP 5.6?

Comment: you need to put more detail and thought into this question, or it will be classified as 'too broad'

Comment: Too broad vote casted

Comment: You can create a `randomPictures()` method in the `Product` model and pass its output as view variables. But I'm not sure if you're asking that... :-?